# Remote debugging a docker container through Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker, dockerfile

I am able to successfully enable VSO debugger support to my Docker container running on my local machine like this:

Step 1:
Add the following to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile c:\rtools_setup_x64.exe -Uri https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/RemoteTools.amd64ret.enu.exe;
```

Step 2:Attach to container and run:

```
$>c:/rtools_setup_x64.exe /install /quiet; & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe' /nostatus /silent /noauth /anyuser /nosecuritywarn /port 4020
```

My question:
How do I integrate Step 2 in my Dockerfile?
I tried it like this but it did not work:

```
RUN & "c:/rtools_setup_x64.exe" /install /quiet
RUN & "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe" /nostatus /silent /noauth /anyuser /nosecuritywarn /port 4020
```

Comment: Also, the project I am working on is an ASp.NET Core turned into .NET Framework one so there is no way to add native Docker support through Visual Studio (by right clicking -> Add Docker Support)--as this is not a supported scenario. So no way to add docker compose yml unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

you can install remote debuger from dockerfile using this command:

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/RemoteTools.amd64ret.enu.exe -OutFile vs_remotetools.exe ; \
.\vs_remotetools.exe /install /quiet
```